# RPM to MSI wrapper?

Tags: windows-installer, rpm

I was wondering if any efforts have been made to create MSI files from rpm spec files or if there are any good ports of RPM to Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want is a cross platform way to lay down files and perform some actions, take a look at [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page).

Answer (score 1):

MSI is an entirely different architecture and way of thinking to RPM, so I'll ask the obvious question - why?

Comment: Making cross platform packages that simply need to lay down files, set some permissions, have a pre, post, preun, and postun section and maybe some information to put in the add remove programs should be simple enough.  I would imagine that I am not the first who packages up stuff for Linux, AIX, Windows, HP, etc.  I am aware they are different technologies but at their core they lay down files and do some stuff to a box.

Answer (score 0):

maybe it's possible to convert deb in Cygwin package ? 
setup.hint is not so different than controle file from a debian package !

developement in progress ...

Answer (score 0):

Acresso's InstallAnywhere is specifically designed for cross-platform installations:
http://www.acresso.com/products/ia/installanywhere-overview.htm

> InstallAnywhere gives
>   software developers a quick and easy
>   way to author professional software
>   installations for Solaris, HP-UX, AIX,
>   Linux, IBM i, Mac OS X, Windows, and
>   more. It saves you time by creating a
>   single project file that generates a
>   reliable installer for each platform
>   you target.

Answer (score 0):

The [Cpack](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/CMake%3aPackaging_With_CPack) is one of the choices for you.

Answer (score 0):

RPM was built for *Nix systems. Not windows.